# Run A Section Of Code In PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm

I am moving from R to Python and have been loving PyCharm for it's similarities to my beloved RStudio. However, someone I can't seem to figure out how to do is run a selection of code in a script.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can select the code you want to run, right-click, and select 'Execute Selection in Console'. The keyboard shortcut for this is ALT+SHIFT+E on Windows

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

1. Open Django console
2. Select your code and press Ctrl+Alt+E. It will execute the code in Django console.

Comment: If he actually uses Django. Most of us don't

Answer (score 0):

now PyCharm has scientific project, when you creating a new project